# I have an issue with a contact form. Works on localhost. When deployed its giving error when attempting to post it via the submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, contact-form, system.net.mail

I have a simple contact form on my Godaddy hosted Asp.net core 2.0 Razor pages website.  Everything works fine on localhost. When the website is deployed, If I click the submit button I receive an error 500 "unable to handle the request".  Below is code for the page:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="row gtr-uniform gtr-50">
         <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
             <input  asp-for="Sendmail.FName" placeholder="First Name"/>
             <span asp-validation-for="Sendmail.FName" style="color:red;"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
             <input  asp-for="Sendmail.LName" placeholder="Last Name" />
             <span asp-validation-for="Sendmail.LName" style="color:red;"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
             <input asp-for="Sendmail.PhoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" />
             <span asp-validation-for="Sendmail.PhoneNumber" style="color:red;"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-12">
             <select asp-for="Sendmail.BestTimeToCall">
                 <option value="">- Best Time To Call-</option>
                 <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
                 <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
                 <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
             </select>
             <span asp-validation-for="Sendmail.BestTimeToCall" style="color:red;"></span>
         </div>            
         <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
                <input asp-for="Sendmail.EmailAddress" placeholder="Email" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Sendmail.EmailAddress" style="color:red;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <select asp-for="Sendmail.PreferredContactMethod">
                    <option value="">- Preferred Contact Method -</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Phone">Phone Call</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Sendmail.PreferredContactMethod" style="color:red;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <textarea asp-for="Sendmail.MessageBody" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Sendmail.MessageBody" style="color:red;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><button asp-page-handler="ContactUs" class="primary" id="contactsubmitbutton">Submit</button></li>
                   
                    <li>@ViewBag.Message</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The following is the controller for the ContactUs page (email and password removed):

```
 public Email Sendmail { get; set; }
        public async Task OnPost()
        {
            try 
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                        //this is the email address you want the contact form to be sent to. example contactrequestform@thevillagementalhealthgroup.com
                        string To = "email@gmail.com";
                        //this is what the subject line of the email will say.  use a subject line that will be easy to identify
                        string Subject = "New Contact Request From The Village Mental Health Group's Contact Us Form";
                        //this is the body of the email
                        string Body = Sendmail.Body;
                        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
                        //this is the to section of the email
                        mm.To.Add(To);
                        //this is the subject section of the email
                        mm.Subject = Subject;
                        //this is what the body of the email message will contain.  Currently it has the input values from the contact form in a readable format
                        mm.Body = "You have a new message from your contact us form on TheVillageMentalHealthgroup.com. Their information is as follows: First Name: " + Sendmail.FName +  " Last Name: " + Sendmail.LName + " Phone Number: " + Sendmail.PhoneNumber + " Best Time To Call: " + Sendmail.BestTimeToCall + " Email Address: " + Sendmail.EmailAddress + " Preferred contact Method: " + Sendmail.PreferredContactMethod + " Their message is as follows: " + Sendmail.MessageBody;
                        //this signifies if the email body is html format.  if you change to yes you can format the email message with html mark up
                        mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
                        //this is where the email is being sent from.  this should be set to the email address specific to the contact form so you will always automatically know it is a contact request from said website
                        mm.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
                        //this is the email providers smtp address
                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        //these are user names and password for the email provider
                        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(mm);
                        //this is the message displayed next to the submit button showing successful submission of of contact request
                        ViewData["Message"] = "Thank You. Your has been sent successfully.We will be in contact with as soon as we are available.";
                }
                else
                {
                    //this is the message displayed if there is an issue submitting the form
                    ViewData["Message"] = "There is an issue with the Contact Form. Please contact us by phone or email.";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = ex;
                Response.Redirect("ContactFormError");
            }

        }
```

It works fine on local host but will not submit email once published to the server. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.  I have been search and looking and trying to work this out for several days now.

Comment: Is server on a corporate network?  On a corportate Network with a Outlook server all port 587 is port forwarded to a proxy server and will not go through firewall to gmail.com.

Comment: It is godaddy hosted server.

Comment: You have to contact godaddy and see if they allow your server to connect to gmail.  Not sure if their firewall will allow connections to other mail servers.  See : https://www.godaddy.com/help/server-and-port-settings-for-workspace-email-6949.

Comment: Thank you.  I just changed it over to a godaddy email and it is giving me the same error.  This is soooo frustrating.

Comment: Change to false.  True is using settings from a POP account,  You are using a username and password. : smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out.  First GoDaddy doesn't allow outside servers on their shared hosting plan.  So after changing to use their relay-hosting.secureserver.net smtp server I was still receiving errors.  I ended up sending the Exception error to the production page by way of passing the viewdata captured in the catch(Exception ex) to the Contact Us page so I could trouble shoot.  I noticed at that point it did not update the content of my page view.  After some other checks I found that while publishing, my views and models were not being updated.  After numerous attempts to force it to change, what ended up working was to change the publish configuration from release to debug, upload and then change back to release and upload again.  from there this is the code that worked
***note*** credentials were not required if hosting from a godaddy hosting account associated with the email.

```
        public async Task OnPost()
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //this is the email address you want the contact form to be sent to. example email@email.com
                    string To = "destination@email.com";
                    
                    //this is what the subject line of the email will say.  use a subject line that will be easy to identify
                    string Subject = "New Contact Request From ...";
                    //this is the body of the email
                    string Body = Sendmail.Body;
                    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
                    //this is the to section of the email
                    mm.To.Add(To);
                    //this is the subject section of the email
                    mm.Subject = Subject;
                    //this is what the body of the email message will contain.  Currently it has the input values from the contact form in a readable format
                    mm.Body = "You have a new message from your contact us form on yoursite.com. </br>" +
                        " Their information is as follows:" +
                        " </br> First Name: " + Sendmail.FName + 
                        " </br> Last Name: " + Sendmail.LName + 
                        " </br> Phone Number: " + Sendmail.PhoneNumber + 
                        " </br> Best Time To Call: " + Sendmail.BestTimeToCall + 
                        " </br> Email Address: " + Sendmail.EmailAddress +
                        " </br> Preferred contact Method: " + Sendmail.PreferredContactMethod + 
                        " </br> Their message is as follows: " + Sendmail.MessageBody;
                    //this signifies if the email body is html format.  if you change to yes you can format the email message with html mark up
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    //this is where the email is being sent from.  this should be set to the email address specific to the contact form so you will always automatically know it is a contact request from said website
                    mm.From = new MailAddress("godaddyhostedemail@domain.com");
                    //this is the email providers smtp address
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
                    smtp.Port = 25;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mm);
                    //this is the message displayed next to the submit button showing successful submission of of contact request
                    ViewData["Message"] = "Thank You. Your has been sent successfully. We will be in contact with as soon as we are available.";
                }
                else
                {
                    //this is the message displayed if there is an issue submitting the form
                    ViewData["Message"] = "There is an issue with the Contact Form. Please contact us by phone or email.";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = ex;
                //Response.Redirect("ContactFormError");
            }

        }
```

below is the model for Email.  it is named Email.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespaceHere.Models
{
    public class Email
    {
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Your first name is required."), MinLength(2), MaxLength(50), Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required."), MinLength(2), MaxLength(50), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Your phone number is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number.  Must be all numbers no spaces or other characters.")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please let us know the best time to contact you."), Display(Name = "Select the best time frame for us to contact you.")]
        public string BestTimeToCall { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), Required(ErrorMessage ="A valid email address is required"), Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [ Required(ErrorMessage ="Please let us know your required contact method"), Display(Name = "Select your preferred method for us to contact you.")]
        public string PreferredContactMethod { get; set; }
        [ Required(ErrorMessage ="Please check the box to prove you are human"), Display(Name = "Check to box to prove you are human")]
        public bool Human { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please let us know how we can assist you."), MinLength(4), MaxLength(500), Display(Name = "Enter your message here.")]
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    }
}
```